# How to get next non null value in SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I have a field and want to get the index of the next non null value. I know that we can easily get the index of the last non null value doing this :

```
@SINCE0(not(@NULL(@FIELD)))
```

Is there a way to go forward in the data and get the next not null value in SPSS modeler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a function equivalent to the `@SINCE0` that will look forward in the data, however, you can probably get the same result if you were to reverse the sort order of your data and then use the `@SINCE0` function to look back.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `@OFFSET(var,expr)` in a derive node. Just remember to sort the data first because it depends on that also.

[Reference from IBM SPSS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/performance_clem_expr.htm)